# Why are these badges a requirement to be eligible as a moderator candidate?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

The [Moderator Election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12) states:

> **Candidates must have all the following badges:**
>
> - Civic Duty
> - Strunk & White.
> - Deputy
> - Convention

There are a lot of people who do not have those badges but appear to be eligible to be a moderator.

Does Stack Overflow have any other alternative option or requirements to nominate themselves in the moderator election, or apply for the moderator role outside of an election? If there is please let me know. I really want to apply and give my best to help the community.

*Let's not let only badges decide anyone's capability*

Comment: How else are we supposed to *decide anyone's capability*?

Comment: I don't know but let me ask it to others.

Comment: Apart from the badges, you also need a minimum of 3000 reputation to contest in the election.

Comment: Related: [Why is the “Convention” badge required for moderator nominations?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352414/why-is-the-convention-badge-required-for-moderator-nominations)

Comment: MSE duplicate: [Relax badge requirements for moderator elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111302/relax-badge-requirements-for-moderator-elections)

Comment: If you "*really want to apply and give your best to help the community*" please use the existing tools made available to you. You have cast 0 votes, raised 0 flags and edited only 2 posts.

Comment: Do you really trust a person who hasn't cast 80 flags yet to moderate the community?

Answer (score 13):

To get those badges you will have to perform certain activities.The responsibilities of a moderator is very much related to those activities as well.

For example Deputy badge is given for flagging(helpful) 80 posts. As a moderator you will have to deal with flags and having an idea of what content is flag-able and what is not is necessary to perform as a moderator.

Comment: Ok like 50 reputations to comment its 80 flaggings for moderator. Recently I have started contributing on this platform, no offense but this site has lots of restriction for new users.

Comment: Well...a new user who does not know well enough about the platform is not really a good candidate to be a moderator. Regarding comment you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep and it's really not that tough to get 50 rep..all you need is ask few good questions

Comment: I think asking Questions is hard, especially good ones, so I'm not with you on "all you need is..". Answering is way easier.

Comment: Ok, might be new users do not know well enough about the platform, but what about someone like me, I am using StackOverflow for a long time but I just started contributing so I have less reputation and badge. I know well enough about the platform so am I capable? No, I am not I don't have enough badge. This is just my feelings, Please do not get offended.

Comment: @PrabeshGouli For someone who "know well enough about the platform" this question and the next one shows surprising lack of research effort... "This is just my feelings, Please do not get offended.".

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for participating, I got what I need. Please someone do 'status-completed' to this.

Comment: @PrabeshGouli you are a member since only 2years. This doesn't count as *long time*. It's indeed very short.

Comment: We don't mark discussions as [[meta-tag:status-completed]], @Prabesh. That mostly only applies to [[meta-tag:feature-request]]s, and occasionally to certain [[meta-tag:support]] requests.

Comment: @Prabesh time spent as a user isn't super meaningful though... How much activity do you have, how much do you know about how we work? How much of the culture of the site, of what's good and not, have you shown? None :/. That's why the badges are important

Comment: @PrabeshGouli  *"Please someone do 'status-completed' to this"* ... doesn't this show that *"I know well enough about the platform"* isn't that true? You know _some_ parts about the plattform, but nothing/not much about the important parts for a mod, like flagging, close voting, reviews.

Comment: There is no circumstance where someone who has been an inactive/passive member for a long time would be a good moderator. Would you hire a programmer that has never coded but can show you they've spent a couple years watching videos on coding? Even having attained these badges, it's very unlikely that alone qualifies one for a moderator. They're a minimal filter to avoid wasting time with people who can't do the moderator equivalent of [fizz buzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz).