# How are we supposed to determine a candidates' suitability for the moderator role?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I recently asked a question regarding what I felt about the process of choosing a moderator for Stack Overflow: [Why specified badge is required to apply for moderator?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399278/why-are-these-badges-a-requirement-to-be-eligible-as-a-moderator-candidate)

I have another follow-up question from the comments:

Other than deciding the moderator capabilities/eligibility by the badges they have earned, what another ways can we find out more about the candidates?

Comment: Go to their user profile. Look at the activity and contributions. In particular, their moderation activity (flags, edits, close votes, duplicates: do they *moderate* well, in your estimation?) and their posts on Meta (do their positions on the issues align with your own?). Second priority: look at their posts on Main (do they answer questions which you think represent the kind of content you want on the site? Do their answers represent the kind of content you want on the site?). Badges and rep are just a high-level summary of these activities.

Comment: Read their meta posts, where they express their opinions.

Comment: I admire your enthusiasm, but it seems you're treating a moderator position like a knighthood, a title, or a given power, while ignoring the work they have to put in everyday. If you want to start the rocky path towards being a mod, you'd have to gain some reverence as an exemplary member of the community, by answering a lot of questions, and engaging in a lot of moderation activities *before* you become a moderator. Most of the candidates you see right now have been helping moderate the site for years, and will continue to do so even if not elected.

Answer (score 13):

If you participate in the [Election Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217027/2020-stack-overflow-moderator-election-chat), currently there is a bot *(a.k.a. ElectionBot)* that will provide an answer to these example variants of this frequently-asked question:

- who to vote for
- how to decide (*who to vote for*)
- how to choose (*who to vote for*)
- how to pick (*who to vote for*)
- how (*are we supposed to*) determine (*a candidate's capability*)
- how (*are we supposed to*) determine (*the capability of nominees*)

Bot response:

> If you want to make an informed decision on who to vote for, you can read the candidates' answers in the election Q&A, and you also can look at examples of their participation on Meta and how they conduct themselves.

Comment: You could have answered with the bot account too.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I recommend the following process.

To understand who you want to elect, you must first understand what you're electing them for. [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) can help.

A certainly non-exhaustive task list is:

- Handle tons and tons of flags. Specifically, flags raised automatically by the system, custom flags by users, flags on comments, and rude/abusive/spam flags. These include things like duplicate answers, handling plagiarism, and much more.
- Detect malicious patterns, such as voting rings, spam networks, consistent unwanted behaviour, or the use of multiple accounts for malicious purposes such as harassment and avoidance of restrictions, and handle them appropriately
- Guide users, both individually in response to flags, and on meta on publicly relevant issues
- Be a representative of users to the company, specifically in response to changes that are yet to be made public
- Manage tags by merging them, creating synonyms, and burninating them
- Resolving conflicts between users, such as disagreements on if a question should be closed or deleted, or on edits

For each of these task, you should ask yourself the following:

- Do I find this task particularly relevant, and is this something I wish to consider when voting?
- Does this candidate have particular experience on this task, for example, having raised many flags previously, participating in guiding users and representing users on meta, or participating in managing tags.

  If so, do I consider this experience to be in line what I'd want of a moderator, or not. For example, was the guidance appropriate in my opinion, and do I think the candidate was right or wrong in closing questions or performing review tasks previously
- Has this candidate expressed a particular opinion or commitment in the questionnaire or on meta on this task, and is this according to what I'd want from a moderator?
- Most subjectively, do I think this candidate will handle this task similar to how I'd want this task to be handled?

Furthermore, since I want the moderator I vote for to do well in the future, I consider if they are committed to making a significant time investment in this site, and are likely to do well under pressure and when attacked in discussions.

The sources available to research are mainly a user's profile, both on main for the amount of flags raised and recent activity in voting and reviewing, and on meta for their previous contributions representing and guiding users.

There is also the content shared on the election page, such as the questionnaires, comments of other users and the candidates (lack of) replies, and, if all else fails, the candidate score and reputation, which are at best indirectly relevant for how qualified a candidate is.

I personally start with the election page, make a shortlist, and then do additional research on the tasks I find most important to determine a final order, especially for my top picks.